# How to to create schema and tables in oracle NoSQL using its Java API

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am using `oracle.nosql.client-3.2.5.jar`.

I am able to create schema and tables in oracle NoSQL using the shell.

But is it possible to do this via its Java API? If yes, any pointer on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a beginner in ONS & did some research on this. Programmatically it can be done like this:

```
public void createTable() {
    TableAPI tableAPI = store.getTableAPI();
    StatementResult result = null;
    String statement = null;

    try {

        statement =
            "CREATE TABLE myTable (" +
            "item STRING," +
            "description STRING," +
            "count INTEGER," +
            "percentage DOUBLE," +
            "PRIMARY KEY (item))";"

        result = store.executeSync(statement);


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid statement:\n" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (FaultException e) {
        System.out.println
            ("Statement couldn't be executed, please retry: " + e);
    }
}
```

Souce: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/NOSQL/html/GettingStartedGuideTables/tablesapi.html#tabledefine